# Why was Mike convicted?

Tags: plot-explanation, suits

What law was violated? What crime did he commit?
From what I understand, the problem was; practicing law, without a law degree. Which, as far as I'm aware, isn't a crime.

Comment: [You can actually get penalties for practicing law without a license.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practicing_without_a_license)

Comment: Maybe this is obvious to everyone but me, but, what show or movie?

Comment: @userLTK look at the tags. [suits] *"An American legal drama television series created and written by Aaron Korsh, debuted in 2011"*

Comment: I looked into this a long time ago. ISTR that some states require a law degree to practice law (as well as passing the bar exam). Other states don't require a law degree to take and pass the bar exam.

Comment: @Riker Could it be that OP was not talking about ' Anyone who claims to have a license and refuses to identify themselves properly by first and last name can possibly lose any one or all of their licenses'? Perhaps OP was thinking it's not a crime to practice without a license where practice would not involve a claim, explicit or implicit, of having a license.

Answer (score 3):

## Fraud

The quote is...

> "Michael James Ross, you're under arrest for conspiracy to commit fraud."

and

> "By my estimation, you've worked on 88 legal cases in your so-called career, and you **committed fraud** every time you picked up the phone, mailed a letter, signed your name, or appeared in court. Each instance carries a nine-month sentence, and to tell you the truth, I am too tired to do the addition."

[**ABC News**](http://abcnews.go.com/Entertainment/suits-star-patrick-adams-explains-mike-ross-prison/story?id=40103713)

> In the gasp-inducing season 5 finale, the smooth-talker with the photographic memory, portrayed by actor Patrick J. Adams, was handed down a two-year sentence for fraud after practicing law without a degree for the last five years.